# A Plethora of Plurals

Tags: wordplay, english, word-game

Please find words that have the following properties:

1. A word that becomes its plural when the letter "s" at the end is dropped.
2. A word that becomes its plural when the first two letters are swapped.
3. Three words that become their plurals when letters are added to the beginning.
4. A word that has no letters in common with one of its plurals.
5. Three words that are plurals of two different words each.

Good luck!

Comment: Does a pluralized word need to be the plural of the original?

Comment: @kayzeroshort Yes, sorry for not adding that. Edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: The language is not specified. Should we assume English?

Comment: @Édouard The question is tagged as English so...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's see if these are what you're looking for!

1.

> Per Rubio's suggestion, perhaps millionairess-> millionaires??

2.

> Incredibly obscure: "Falaj" and "Aflaj".

3.

> Yes -> Ayes. Then two very obscure ones: Loti -> Maloti and Xhosa -> Amaxhosa.

4.

> Cow, which pluralizes archaically to "kine".

5.

> Crosses (Cross/Crosse), Axes (Ax/Axis), Ellipses (Ellipsis, Ellipse)

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear enough in my instructions. I have edited my question accordingly. Number 4 and number 5 are correct, though.

Comment: Got it! I'll get back to work then. :)

Comment: All correct except for number 1. For 3 I was going for "sente" -> "lisente", but yours works too.

Comment: rot47 *>:==:@?2:C6DD @C 3:==:@?2:C6DD* without the final "s" becomes plural without (strictly speaking) changing gender ...

Comment: Since you're so close, I'll give you the checkmark now.

Answer (score 3):

Q1:

> A bit of a stretch, but **timeliness** describes how timely something is, i.e. its timeline. The plural of timeline is **timelines**.

Q4:

> **I**, which has **we** as its plural.

Q5:

> **Axes** is the plural of both **axe** and **axis**.
> **Bases** is the plural of both **base** and **basis**.
> **Ellipses** is the plural of both **ellipse** and...**ellipsis**.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to Q1:

> Princess -> Princes changes both plurality and gender.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: Q2

> acts --> cats

This was made before a clarification edit, so this answer isn't valid anymore.

Answer (score 1):

1. > Caress doesn't become its plural, but becomes a plural, scares. I also think schools would work in another sense, where school is the collective noun for a group of fish.

2.

3.

4. > I think a lot of collective nouns work here; also collateral adjectives could technically work here. For instance: bee, colony or apian.

Answer (score 0):

Q4:

> man -> people; boy -> children; mom -> parents

Q5:

> 'Children' is the plural of both 'son' and 'daughter'.
>  'Parents' is the plural of both 'mother' and 'father'. 
>  'siblings' is the plural of both 'brother' and 'sister'.

Comment: Children is the plural of child. Multiple sons would be properly pluralized as sons.